# Convert struct to []json.RawMessage

Tags: json, go

Trying to convert a struct to []json.RawMessage. My understanding is that json.Marshal() converts it to byte[] as is []json.RawMessage. I cannot however seem to convert between the two. My function expects to receive input as `[]json.RawMessage`.

Have tried several different methods including `myIn := json.RawMessage(&myJsonStruct{"string1", "string2"})` and `myIn := (*json.RawMessage)(json.Marshal(&myJsonStruct{"string1", "string2"}))`

```
type myJsonStruct struct {
    myString       string  `json:"myString"`
    mySecongString string  `json:"mySecondString"`
}

myIn := json.Marshal(&myJsonStruct{"string1", "string2"})

myFunction(myIn)

myFunction(receivedIn []json.RawMessage) {
    //do work
    return
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things here:

1. You need to create a new slice of `json.RawMessage` in order to pass that expected type into your function `myFunction` as an argument
2. Store the result of marshaling your custom struct `myJsonStruct` in a variable `myIn` (type `[]byte`)
3. Create a new variable of `myInRaw` (type `json.RawMessage`) and append that to the previously created slice of `json.RawMessage`.

The above steps will then allow you to pass in the slice of `json.RawMessage` to your function for further work to be done.

See example below or working example in the [playground](https://goplay.space/#60VFEe55p1t):

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
)

type myJsonStruct struct {
    myString       string `json:"myString"`
    mySecongString string `json:"mySecondString"`
}

func myFunction(receivedIn []json.RawMessage) {
    //do work
    return
}

func main() {

    var rawJSONSlice []json.RawMessage

    myIn, err := json.Marshal(
        &myJsonStruct{
            myString:       "string1",
            mySecongString: "string2",
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        // catch err
    }

    myInRaw := json.RawMessage(myIn)

    rawJSONSlice = append(rawJSONSlice, myInRaw)

    myFunction(rawJSONSlice)
}
```

Comment: Works perfect and explained well

Comment: I removed the type conversion to string. Since the underlying type of RawMessage is []byte it can (and should) be converted directly.